# Error to separate list of coordinates in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that contains 3 lists with pairs of coordinates. I would like to read the files and separate the first field as a name and the rest as coordinates. However, I don't know how to do this.
I am using the following code to read the txt file.

```
arquivo = open('dados_utm.txt', 'rt')

t = ' '
t1 = ' '

while t != '':
  t = arquivo.readline()
  t1 = t.split(' ')
  print(t1)
```

Output:

> ['Poly', '"Pampulha"', '420545.,8039109.', '421826.,8039269.',
> '424213.,8041682.', '424189.,8043000.', '424331.,8044861.',
> '426457.,8047689.', '427082.,8047013.', '427713.,8044612.',
> '427710.,8042703.', '428712.,8040642.', '428713.,8040196.',
> '428790.,8039499.', '428356.,8038819.', '427844.,8039050.',
> '426759.,8038697.', '426595.,8035314.', '427213.,8033950.',
> '426558.,8030343.', '426113.,8030041.', '420041.,8030502.',
> '419081.,8031438.', '419678.,8037604.', '420545.,8039109.\n']
> ['Poly',
> '"Jacaré"', '425846.,8055763.', '424723.,8057841.',
> '422398.,8058414.', '413568.,8058765.', '410307.,8060688.',
> '403022.,8068114.', '402543.,8071067.', '403423.,8071846.',
> '417134.,8073069.', '419408.,8074047.', '424638.,8068255.',
> '429946.,8065755.', '430183.,8064351.', '433594.,8058696.',
> '434290.,8058940.', '434296.,8057197.', '431016.,8051616.',
> '430041.,8051612.', '428278.,8051122.\n']
> ['Poly', '"Patos"',
> '437525.,7991091.', '439184.,7993615.', '435440.,8005422.',
> '437290.,8006397.', '443981.,8000217.', '445662.,7995572.',
> '448275.,7988217.', '446432.,7984918.', '438654.,7985476.',
> '437525.,7991091.'] ['']

The second step is to separate the x and y coordinates for different variables. For this I am using the following code.

```
for i in t1[1,0]:
   x = []
   y = []
   xy = t1.readline()
   xy = xy.split(',')
   x.append(float(xy[0]))
   y.append(float(xy[1]))
   print(x, y)
```

However I have the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

txt file:

> Poly "Pampulha" 420545.,8039109. 421826.,8039269. 424213.,8041682.
> 424189.,8043000. 424331.,8044861. 426457.,8047689. 427082.,8047013. 427713.,8044612. 427710.,8042703. 428712.,8040642. 428713.,8040196. 428790.,8039499. 428356.,8038819. 427844.,8039050. 426759.,8038697. 426595.,8035314. 427213.,8033950. 426558.,8030343. 426113.,8030041. 420041.,8030502. 419081.,8031438. 419678.,8037604. 420545.,8039109.
> Poly "Jacaré" 425846.,8055763. 424723.,8057841. 422398.,8058414.
> 413568.,8058765. 410307.,8060688. 403022.,8068114. 402543.,8071067. 403423.,8071846. 417134.,8073069. 419408.,8074047. 424638.,8068255. 429946.,8065755. 430183.,8064351. 433594.,8058696. 434290.,8058940. 434296.,8057197. 431016.,8051616. 430041.,8051612. 428278.,8051122.
> Poly "Patos" 437525.,7991091. 439184.,7993615. 435440.,8005422.
> 437290.,8006397. 443981.,8000217. 445662.,7995572. 448275.,7988217. 446432.,7984918. 438654.,7985476. 437525.,7991091.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `t1[1, 0]` is not possible with lists... What did you want it to do?

Comment: Hi @Tomerikoo I would like to create two distinct variables x and y. Then create 3 polygons. One for each line.

Comment: That still doesn't help understand what you meant for the expression above so we can't know how to suggest you to fix it

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not clear @Tomerikoo I'm learning Python and I don't know if my code is correct. I have this file that I sent. I would like to read this file and then calculate the area of ​​each polygon. For this I did the first step, read the file and then I tried to separate the coordinates in the second loop.

Comment: Can you add expected data to your question?

Comment: And yet again you didn't explain in your own words what you expect the expression `for i in t1[1, 0]:` to do...

Answer (score 2):

You need more than one list because you're overwriting t1, you got that error from having [1, 0] after t1 in your for loop, t1 is a list so readline() won't work.

This should work and put coords as lists of tuples into dict t2 with the names as keys:

```
arquivo = open('dados_utm.txt', 'rt')

t = None
t1 = []
while t != '':
    t = arquivo.readline()
    t1.append(t.split(' '))

t2 = {}
for a in t1:
    name = a.pop(0) + ' ' + a.pop(1)
    t2[name] = []
    for ele in a:
        xy = ele.split(',')
        x, y = float(xy[0]), float(xy[1])
        t2[name].append((x, y))
print(t2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I am getting the following error: 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Sorry, it's late, I messed up. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to think about pandas its a good library.

```
text = open('untitled.txt', 'rt').read()
lst = [item for item in text.split('\n') if item]
lst = [item.split(' ') for item in lst]
t2 = {}
for itr in lst:
    name = ''.join(itr[0:2]).replace('"',' ')
    t2[name] = {}
    df = pd.DataFrame(map(lambda x: x.split(','),itr[2:]),columns=["X","Y"])
    t2[name] = {
            "X": df["X"].to_list(),
            "Y": df["Y"].to_list()
        }
print(t2)
```